# retrieve image from database using spring mvc

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

UserEntityManager.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "getImages.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public byte[] getImage(final String username) {
    Blob img = null;
    byte[] imgData = null;
    sql = "SELECT UserPhoto FROM u_logininfo WHERE LoginName = ?";

    try {
        img = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[]{username}, new RowMapper<Blob>() {

            @Override
            public Blob mapRow(ResultSet rs, int arg1)
                    throws SQLException {
                Blob blob = rs.getBlob("UserPhoto");
                return blob;
            }

        });

        imgData = img.getBytes(1, (int) img.length());
        return imgData;
        //File file = new File
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

And this is my controller

UserController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "getImages.do" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
private ModelAndView viewImages(Model model){
    String userName = (String)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
    byte[] image = userEntityManager.getImage(userName);
    model.addAttribute("images", image);
    return new ModelAndView("Fun Zone/Photo");
}
```

and jsp

```
<div class="col-sm-2" style="margin-top: 288px; margin-left: 291px;">
    <img src="getImages.do">
</div>
```

I want to display the image on the .jsp page using Spring MVC 3 But image not display in jsp.

Comment: Can you check browser console, what error it is giving?

Comment: http://localhost:8081/demo/getImages.do method call and nothing error show in console

Comment: Why UserEntityManager has a request mapping like this? @RequestMapping(value = "getImages.do", method = RequestMethod.GET) on it?  It's a service or DAO right?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to rewrite the controller. There seems so many things that are not exactly the way it's supposed to be. Do something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "getImages.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void viewImages(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        // get the image
        String userName = (String)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
        byte[] image = userEntityManager.getImage(userName);              

        // get MIME type of the file
        String mimeType = "application/octet-stream";

        // set content attributes for the response
        response.setContentType(mimeType);
        response.setContentLength((int) image.length());

        // set headers for the response
        String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
        String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=image.jpeg");
        response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

        // get output stream of the response
        OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();

        // get input stream and a fixed size buffer
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(image);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

        // write data into output stream
        int read = -1;
        while(read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
             outStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }

        // close output stream
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close(); 
}
```

And also get rid of that RequestMapping on UserEntityManager.